# Free SMS to shortcodes/Magic?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts, google-voice

My current cellular plan does not include free SMS, so I'm trying to find an alternative way to send SMS for free from my Android phone. In particular, I'm trying to use the [Magic service](https://getmagicnow.com/), which interacts via an SMS short code. I have attempted to use:

- Google Hangouts/Voice - but I do not get a response from the Magic short code
- TextPlus - but it does not recognize short codes as valid numbers
- XFinity Voice - but it does not recognize short codes as valid numbers

Any ideas on how to get free SMS's to Magic?

Answer (score 1):

I emailed Magic, and got a response that it is possible to use a regular phone number instead of the shortcode: `+1 (408) 707-3077`

Magic can then be used with the methods outlined in the original question (e.g. Google Hangouts/Voice, TextPlus, XFinity, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Every Android phones include
[Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk).
When you ask people their phone number, you can also ask them their email address to send them messages via Hangouts. However, if some people hate Hangouts, you can use
[Google Allo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball)
to send messages that will be received as SMS.

Comment: That didn't answer the question.